# Conditional Formatting Top and Bottom Percentage

Tags: ms-access, formatting, conditional-statements

Is there a way to apply conditional formatting to change the color of a field on a continuous form to show the top and bottom 20% of values? Similar to what Excel can do with ranking.

Comment: change your tag from `access` to `ms-access` and you might get some help, but unlikely as it doesn't seem like a programming question

Answer (score 0):

Do two queries that pull the `TOP 20%`, one ascending and one descending. Then two rules in Conditional Formatting like:

`Field Value Is greater than or equal to DMin("fieldname","queryTOP")`

`Field Value Is less than or equal to DMax("fieldname","queryBOT")`